Flutter Web App Shows Grey Screen on First Load
I am developing a Flutter project for the web. When I load the app in a browser for the first time, it displays a grey screen. However, if I refresh the page or reload it, the app displays the data correctly.
This issue only happens on the first load.
There are no significant errors in the console during the first load.

More info will help us to help you!

This issue seems specific to the web platform. If the app runs fine on mobile devices, clearing the browser cache might resolve it. Alternatively, it could be due to an await function delaying the initial load. Please provide a screenshot or video of the issue to help diagnose further.

Update you Web >> index.html body with that i mean loading widget at the time of loading
   <body>
     <div id="loading_indicator" class="container"
      style="height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align- 
      items: center;">
      <img class="indicator" src="./assets/Loading Lines.gif" 
      style="height: 150px; max-width: 150px;" />
    </div>
    <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
   </body>

